# Read only List<T> view and covariance

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, covariance

I wanted to make a read-only indexable "view" of a list, with the slight twist that the read only view should enumerate to an interface of the list type.

```
interface IIndexable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
   T this[int i] { get; }
   int Count { get; }
}
```

The usage scenario would look something like this.

```
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>[]{ dog1, dog2 }; // Dog implements IAnimal

IIndexable<IAnimal> animals = dogs.AsIIndexable<Dog, IAnimal>();
IAnimal first = animals[0];
```

I thought this would be possible given covariance and type constraints, but maybe I'm mistaken here. 
My first attempt looks like this, which doesn't work because of the type of the enumerator.

```
internal class ListIndexable<TC, T> : IIndexable<T> where TC : T
{
   private List<TC> list;
   public ListIndexable(List<TC> list) { this.list = list; }

   public T this[int i] { get { return list[i]; } }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
   {
      return list.GetEnumerator(); // Computer says no.
   }
}
```

Why can't I return an `IEnumerator<TC>` as an `IEnumerator<T>`? The type is covariant and I have constrained it with TC : T. Would it really be unsafe to return an `IEnumerator<TC>`, or is it simply a weakness here that the compiler's reasoning ignores the type constraint?

I could solve it by using a custom enumerator that wraps the `IEnumerator<TC>` and returns its items as `T`'s which is of course perfectly legal, but I'm just curious why the above solution can't work.

```
internal class ListIndexable<TC, T> : IIndexable<T> where TC : T
{
   private List<TC> list;
   public ListIndexable(List<TC> list) { this.list = list; }

   public T this[int i] { get { return list[i]; } }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
   {
      return new Enumerator(list.GetEnumerator()); 
   }

   class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
   {
      private IEnumerator<TC> inner;
      internal Enumerator(IEnumerator<TC> inner) { this.inner = inner; }

      public bool MoveNext()
      {
         return inner.MoveNext();
      }

      public T Current
      {
         get { return inner.Current; }
      }

      // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Why does `ListIndexable` have two type parameters? An `IIndexable<Dog>` is an `IIndexable<IAnimal>` due to covariance.

Comment: Why not use ReadOnlyCollection? Why are you creating your own class?

Comment: @Lee that IS a good question

Comment: I don't know if the real question was lost in the noise of the contrived example: the question is about type constraints i.e. "Why can't I return...", it's not about solving this particular concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code does not work because of value types. You cannot do the following:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = new[] { 1, 2 };
IEnumerable<object> os = ints;
```

so the compiler won't accept your definition since it can't guarantee that `IEnumerable<TC>` is compatible with `IEnumerable<T>` in general. If you add `class` constraints to `T` and `TC` it compiles:

```
internal class ListIndexable<TC, T> : IIndexable<T> where TC : class, T where T : class
{
}
```

However, you can define `ListIndexable` with only one type parameter instead of two. If you change your definition to:

```
internal class ListIndexable<T> : IIndexable<T>
{
   private List<T> list;
   public ListIndexable(List<T> list) { this.list = list; }

   public T this[int i] { get { return list[i]; } }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
   {
      return list.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

then you can do:

```
IIndexable<IAnimal> animals = dogs.AsIIndexable();
```

where `AsIndexable` can be defined simply as:

```
public static ListIndexable<T> AsIndexable<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    return new ListIndexable<T>(list);
}
```

Comment: That solves my problem, but the problem itself was just there to illustrate a question I had about type constraints and covariance. This solution just shows my example to be stupid/contrived but it still holds as an example of type constraints + covariance I think
(I *will* use this solution in my code, thank you, an upvote for you even though it dosn't answer the question) :)

Comment: @AndersForsgren - I would guess it's because of value types - you can't do `IEnumerable<int> ints = new[] { 1, 2 }; IEnumerable<object> os = ints;`. So in your case the compiler can't guarentee that `IEnumerator<TC>` is compatible with `IEnumerator<T>` in general.

Comment: @AndersForsgren - You can get it to compiler if you restrict, `T` and `TC` to be classes, see update.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to create a read-only collection, you can use [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to wrap your list, eg:

```
var dogs = new List<Dog> {new Dog{Name="A"}, new Dog{Name="B"}, new Dog{Name="C"}};
var ro=new ReadOnlyCollection<Dog>(dogs);

IEnumerable<IAnimal> a = ro;
```

Comment: That works, and @Lee 's answer (That two type parameters are just not necessary) of course also solves the problem. But the question wasn't about solving a problem, the question was about how the compiler combines (or doesn't combine) generic type constraints with covariance.

Comment: That is not clear from the actual question. Perhaps you should edit it?

Comment: In this concrete problem I don't only need a read only collection, I need an indexable datastructure of generic type `IAnimal`. So something that is `IList<IAnimal>` for example. But `ReadOnlyCollection<Dog>` implements only `IList<Dog>`, not `IList<IAnimal>`.